# C# Winform : Control locked but locked propety is set to false

Tags: c#, winforms, locked

I have a really strange situation in my winform application.

I'm trying to change the design of a certain form but controls are locked so I can't do anything.

If I right click on it, the lock button is not pressed. If I check properties of the control, anything is grayed out but the "locked" property is set to false.

[image: locked control]

The document outline (main form is not locked) :

[image: document outline]

The project is 10 years old and was first made with .NET 2 (now it's in 3.5).
There is a lot of form that I could change, but not this one.

Thx for your help

PS : I don't really want to copy/paste in a new form (the project is a total mess).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's almost certain that the form you are trying to edit is in fact derived from another form - have a look at its base type, and it should be obvious. Whatever controls are on the parent will be locked in the children - all the children share the same controls, so you don't want to move them by accident. If you do want to move them in all children, just open the parent form in the designer.

Comment: First of all, thanks for this really quick reply. That's exactly what you said. Now I can work on this control.
How can I mark this as resolved ?

Comment: @Robouste Glad it helped :) There should be a checkmark next to the vote buttons you can click.